# Show post type taxonomy

Tags: post-type

I'm making a WordPress theme I've copied post-type codes from "AVENUE" theme by "FabThemes".

Codes Are these:

```
<?php 

/* Property Listings*/

function post_type_listings() {
register_post_type(
                    'listings', 
                    array( 'public' => true,
                            'publicly_queryable' => true,
                            'has_archive' => true, 
                            'hierarchical' => false,
                            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/listing.png',
                            'labels'=>array(
                                        'name' => _x('Listings', 'post type general name'),
                                        'singular_name' => _x('Listing', 'post type singular name'),
                                        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'listing'),
                                        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Listing'),
                                        'edit_item' => __('Edit Listing'),
                                        'new_item' => __('New Listing'),
                                        'view_item' => __('View Listing'),
                                        'search_items' => __('Search Listings'),
                                        'not_found' =>  __('No listings found'),
                                        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Listing found in Trash'), 
                                        'parent_item_colon' => ''
                                        ),                           
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            'menu_position'=>5,
                            'query_var' => true,
                            'rewrite' => TRUE,
                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'listing', 'with_front' => FALSE,),
                            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'mytheme_add_box',
                            'supports' => array(
                                        'title',
                                        'thumbnail',
                                        'comments',
                                        'editor'
                                        )
                            ) 
                    );
                } 
add_action('init', 'post_type_listings');

/* Price range taxonomy */

function create_range_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Range', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'range', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Range' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Range' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Range' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Range:' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Range' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Range' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Range' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Range Name' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('range',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'range' ),
  ));
}

/* Location Taxonomy */

function create_location_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Location' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Location' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Location' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Location' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Location' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Location Name' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('location',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
  ));

}

/* Type of property Taxonomy */

function create_property_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Property type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'Property type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Property type' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Property types' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Property type' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Property type' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Property type' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Property type' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Property type' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Property type' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('property',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'property' ),
  ));

}

/* Area Taxonomy */

function create_area_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Area', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'Area', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Areas' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Areas' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Area' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Area' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Area' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Area' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Area' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Area' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('area',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'area' ),
  ));

}


/* Listing type Taxonomy */

function create_type_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Listing type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'Listing type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Listing types' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Listing types' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Listing types' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Listing type' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Listing type' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Listing type' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Listing type' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Listing type' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('type',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => 'radio',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
  ));

}


/* Bedrooms Taxonomy */

function create_bedrooms_taxonomy() 
{
$labels = array(
                              'name' => _x( 'Bedrooms', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                              'singular_name' => _x( 'Bedrooms', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Bedrooms' ),
                              'all_items' => __( 'All Bedrooms' ),
                              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Bedrooms' ),
                              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Bedrooms' ),
                              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Bedrooms' ), 
                              'update_item' => __( 'Update Bedrooms' ),
                              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Bedrooms' ),
                              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Bedrooms' ),
);  
register_taxonomy('bedrooms',array('listings'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bedroom' ),
  ));

}



add_action( 'init', 'create_area_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'create_range_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'create_location_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'create_property_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'create_type_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'create_bedrooms_taxonomy', 0 ); 




/* PRE-DEFINE TERMS */

##Featured##
function add_range_term_featured() {
if(!is_term('Featured', 'type')){
  wp_insert_term('Featured', 'type');
}
}

##Reduced#
function add_range_term_reduced() {
if(!is_term('Reduced', 'type')){
  wp_insert_term('Reduced', 'type');
}
}

##Sold#
function add_range_term_sold() {
if(!is_term('Sold', 'type')){
  wp_insert_term('Sold', 'type');
}
}


add_action( 'init', 'add_range_term_featured' );
add_action( 'init', 'add_range_term_reduced' );
add_action( 'init', 'add_range_term_sold' );





?>
```

With this codes post-types works just fine except one part, when I use of search box to filter results search will work but no any results shown! just index page will be load!

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I want to know what codes have to use and what page have to make to show the search results?

PS> Here is the link of Avenue theme. http://www.fabthemes.com/Avenue/

Answer (score 0):

Set the public parameter in [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) to true like this:

```
public'             => true,
```

**public**
(boolean) (optional) Controls how the type is visible to authors (show_in_nav_menus, show_ui) and readers (exclude_from_search, publicly_queryable).

Default: false

'true' - Implies exclude_from_search: false, publicly_queryable, show_in_nav_menus, and show_ui. The built-in types attachment, page, and post are similar to this.

And [create a search.php file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page).

Comment: Thanks for respond, the problem was `archive.php` I made that and everything works fine. thanks anyway.